# displaying dates in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have the following date

```
start = "16/09/2014"
```

which I convert using "to_date" method to

```
Tue, 16 Sep 2014
```

How can I display above in my view as doing the following doesn't work?

= start.to_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
 start.to_date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y')
```

You have to choose your display options.

---

Another cool way to do it, is to add it to an initializer:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.update my_format: '%a, %d %b %Y'
```

Then you can do:

```
start.to_date.to_s(:my_format)
```